# How to reduce Rails form loading time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a form which has 4 associations and 2 javascript calls. It is taking to load minimum of 10 seconds to load,even for new form. Out of 10 seconds, Active record is taking with in 100 ms and remaining 9990ms are taking to load Views.
(In views page,i am loading tiny mice editor,autocomplete javascript libraries)

Is it possible to load a page loading 4 associations,including 2 javascript libraries in less than 3 seconds? If yes, Pleas any body help me in loading my form much faster?

Thanks in Advance,
Prem.

Comment: Can you provide the logs and sourcecode exerpt please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to check this http://www.railsinside.com/tutorials/230-scaling-rails-a-free-13-part-series-of-screencasts.html.

As said if you have four associations you may have to do eager_loading or may be better write sql and use find_by_sql.

Regarding javascript or view loading you may have to research minifying javascript and css.
You also need to consider using image sprites.

Answer (score 2):

How are you measuring this load time? By timing it in the browser until the page is loaded? TinyMCE does a fair bit, and in development mode you will see that the general performance of your app could be quite slow.

To see how it really performs, deploy the application to a production environment (or create a production setup including DB on your local machine) and run the app with `rails server -e production`

Comment: i am looking at the time specified in logs.(Response time is 10 seconds in development and around 20 seconds in production mode, and actual time to load the page is even a bit more than it is showing in logs)

Comment: You need to post the code for this: view, controller, model. Have you debugged hits to the DB? Try commenting out various parts of the view to see what is taking the bulk of the time. Anything with recursion? Something loading a load of partials?

Answer (score 0):

After doing all the improvements you can by writing better requests, you should consider caching. It's easy to do, the problem is that you have to manage when to invalidate the cache.

Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html for help on how to do it.

Comment: i tried caching either. But i need to update my autocomplete data depending upon other field in form.So i removed cahcing later. Can we do cahcing depending upon condition? Please let me know.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Another really important thing is that when you autocomplete something, you really should pay attention on not making too complicated requests and also index your database on the specified field